# Handling form post, nodejs and JQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, jquery-mobile

I'm working with node.js and jQuery Mobile, and I'm having some problems with handling the form.
How could I render the next page? what should I pass to the render function?

Thanks for the help!

HTML CODE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
     <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
     <form method="POST" action="/main" name="login">User name &nbsp; 
          <input required="required" name="username" type="text" value="">                       <br>
        <br>
        Password &nbsp;&nbsp; <input required="required" name="password" type="password" value=""><br>
        <br>
        <input value="Login" name="Login" type="submit"></form>
  </div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <h1>SUCCESS</h1>
  </div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <h1>FAIL</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

NODE.JS:

```js
app.post("/main", function (req, res) {
.
.
.
if (user != null) {
 console.log("User Found");
    res.render(??????); --> render #page2
} else {
    console.log("Username and password don't match");
    res.render(??????); --> render #page3     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser). It's middleware for express, parser of http body in different formats.

For `Form` parsing use `bodyparser.urlencoded` middleware